# BQ M10 Music App - Creating Playlist of Folders

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, music, bq

I have a number of audio programs that I've converted from cassette tape to MP3s. Each program is in its own folder and the file names go like this:

```
00 Introduction.mp3
01 Some Title.mp3
02 Some Title.mp3
03 Some Title.mp3
```

I've moved these numerous folders to my BQ M10's 128GB microSD card, but I find that the Music app offers no way for me to make playlists on a per folder basis. I'd like to make playlists by indicating a folder, and I want the Music App to recursively queue that folder alphabetically to create a playlist.

I'm I overlooking a feature that makes this possible?

Also, when it comes to music, I've already organized my folders like this:

```
Genre > Artist > Song
```

Again, I want the music app to allow me to create a playlist by indicating a Genre-Folder I've already created, then I want it to recursively queue that folder alphabetically to generate a playlist.

I'm I overlooking a feature that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this shell script to create playlists based on folder back when Jolla's music indexer had a few bugs. Should work just as well on the M10

https://gist.github.com/ShaneQful/385f94786a1880260531#file-gistfile1-sh